# Error <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Erpeo.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Tags: .net

I get this error when i try to run the .net project

---

> Server error in the '/' application.
> Analysis error
> Description: An error occurred while parsing a resource required to respond to this request. Please review the details of the particular scan error below, then edit your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message:

> Could not load type 'Erpeo.MvcApplication'.
>
> Source error:
>
> Line 1: <% @ Application Codebehind = "Global.asax.cs" Inherits = "Erpeo.MvcApplication" Language = "C #"%>
>
> Source file: /global.asax Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version: 4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version: 4.7.3429.0

Comment: Use English please...

Comment: Have you recently changed any configuration related things in the Project? Please restart VS. Sometimes issue will get resolved.

Comment: No i didnt and i already restart VS

Answer (score 0):

Copy the referenced dll files from the binaries into application's bin folder and try.